# CountDown persistente aunque cierre la aplicación

Tags: java, android, android-studio, firebase

Tengo un problema y es que necesito crear un CountDown que se mantenga cuando se cierre la aplicación, lo que trato de hacer es un sistema de Rewards para los usuarios que puedan reclamar cada día.

Logre hacer el CountDown pero aun no logro hacer lo que requiero.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si pueden ver en la esquina superior tengo mi CountDown.

Status.java:

```
package com.liarkat.testwhatatest;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

import org.w3c.dom.Text;

public class Status extends AppCompatActivity {
private static String TAG = "Servicio";

Button contador;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_status);
    contador = findViewById(R.id.txtcountdown);

    //inicia el servicio
    startService(new Intent(Status.this, ServicioTimer.class));

}

private BroadcastReceiver br = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        //aqui obtienes los datos enviados por el servicio
        //obtienes el tiempo que lleva
        if (intent.getExtras() != null){
            if (intent.hasExtra("Tiempo")){
                String tiempo = intent.getStringExtra("Tiempo");
                contador.setText(tiempo);
            } if (intent.hasExtra("Fin")){
                //se recibe que se ha finalizado el contador
                String tiempo = intent.getStringExtra("Fin");
                contador.setText(tiempo);
                contador.setEnabled(true);
                //cierras el servicio ya que no es necesario mantenerlo, sera creado al pulsar el boton nuevamente
                stopService(new Intent(Status.this, ServicioTimer.class));
            }
        }
    }
};

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    registerReceiver(br, new IntentFilter(ServicioTimer.PAQUETE));
    Log.i(TAG, "Broadcast registrado");
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    unregisterReceiver(br);
    Log.i(TAG, "Broadcast desligado");
}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    try {
        unregisterReceiver(br);
    }catch (Exception e){
    }
    super.onStop();
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    stopService(new Intent(Status.this, ServicioTimer.class));
    Log.i(TAG, "Termina el servicio");
    super.onDestroy();
}
```

}

ServicioTimer.java:

```
package com.liarkat.testwhatatest;

import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.CountDownTimer;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.util.Log;

import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class ServicioTimer extends Service {

String FORMAT = "%02d:%02d:%02d";
private static String TAG = "Servicio";
public static final String PAQUETE = "com.liarkat.com.activity_status";
Intent bi = new Intent(PAQUETE);

CountDownTimer cdt = null;

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    Log.i(TAG, "Comienza el timer...");
    cdt = new CountDownTimer(86400000, 1000) {
        @Override
        public void onTick(long l) {
            String tiempo = ""+String.format(FORMAT,
                    TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(l),
                    TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(l)- TimeUnit.HOURS.toMinutes(
                            TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(l)),
                    TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(l) - TimeUnit.MINUTES.toSeconds(
                            TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(l)
                    ));
            //con esto se envia el tiempo
            bi.putExtra("Tiempo", tiempo);
            sendBroadcast(bi);
        }

        @Override
        public void onFinish() {
            //se envia el tiempo finalizado
            bi.putExtra("Fin", "Recoger");
            sendBroadcast(bi);
        }
    }.start();
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    cdt.cancel();
    Log.i(TAG, "Timer cancelado");
    super.onDestroy();
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
}

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}
}
```

Quiero implementarle Firebase para la base de datos, aun no he empezado esa parte, pero si es mas fácil utilizando una base de datos, cuéntenme como, llevo días rompiéndome la cabeza tratando de lograrlo, soy nuevo en el desarrollo de aplicaciones móviles, de hecho esta es mi primera aplicación y quiero que me quede bien estructurada.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EL uso de servicios se [ha vuelto más complicado](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/background) en las ultimas versiones de Andriod.

Para hacer lo que vos estás queriendo hacer evaluá un camino diferente:

Cuando la app está abierta, tenés el `CountDown` corriendo.

Cuando la app se cierra, persistes la hora actual y el valor del `CountDown`.
La persistencia puede ser en `SharedPreferences` o en la base de datos interna si estás usando una.

Cuando la app se vuelve a iniciar, recuperas los valores persistidos y tomas la hora actual. La diferencia entre la hora actual y la hora persistida es el tiempo que pasó desde que se cerró la app. 
El `CowntDown` lo tendrías que setear al valor que tenía a la hora persistida menos el tiempo que pasó desde que se cerró la app.

De esta forma no necesitas usar un servicio.

**EDICIÓN I**

Tanto la hora que se persiste como la hora actual se refieren a la hora como la maneja el sistema, esto es incluyendo el día, el mes y el año aparte de la hora, minutos, y segundos.

Una alternativa es utilizar `System.currentTimeMillis()` que devuelve un long con la cantidad de milisegundos desde el *1ro de Enero de 1970*.

Utilizando este valor, la diferencia entre los dos fechas/horarios estará en milisegundos. Considerando que un día tiene 24hs * 60 mi * 60 seg * 1000 ms, se puede determinar si pasó más de un día.

Probablemente haya otras alternativas usando la librería de java.time de java 8 que ayude con los cálculos de forma menos artesanal.

Ejemplo:

En el ejemplo fijate que en onPause() se cancela el CountDown y se persisten los valores, y en onResume() se reactiva el CountDown con el valor recalculado considerando el tiempo 'off-line'.

Nota: el código comentado agrega un botón para hacer pruebas que provoca el reseteo de los valores persistidos al salir de la app.

**activity_persistent_count_down_activity.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvHora"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="00:00:00"
        />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvMsg"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text=""
        />
    <!-- Button
        android:id="@+id/btnReset"
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:text="RESET Shared Prefs"/ -->
</LinearLayout>
```

**PersistentCountDownActivity.java**

```
public class PersistentCountDownActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final String PRF_COUNTDOWN_FILE = "cdt-preferences";
    private static final String PRF_CDT_LAST_RECORDED = "prf-cdt-last-recorded";
    private static final String PRF_CDT_LAST_VALUE = "prf-cdt-last-value";

    CountDownTimer cdt = null;
    SharedPreferences prefs;

    TextView tvHora, tvMsg;
    volatile long tiempo;
    Button reset;
    static final String FORMAT = "%02d:%02d:%02d";


//    boolean restFlag = false;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_persistent_count_down_activity);

        tvHora = findViewById(R.id.tvHora);
        tvMsg = findViewById(R.id.tvMsg);
//        reset = findViewById(R.id.btnReset);
//        reset.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
//            @Override
//            public void onClick(View view) {
//                resetSharedPrefs();
//            }
//        });
        prefs = getSharedPreferences(PRF_COUNTDOWN_FILE,MODE_PRIVATE);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        long lastRecorded = prefs.getLong(PRF_CDT_LAST_RECORDED, -1);
        long lastValue = prefs.getLong(PRF_CDT_LAST_VALUE, -1);
        setupCDT(lastRecorded, lastValue);
        if(cdt != null){
          cdt.start();
        }
    }

    @SuppressLint("ApplySharedPref")
    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        if(cdt != null){
          cdt.cancel();
        }
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
//        if(restFlag){
//            editor.putLong(PRF_CDT_LAST_RECORDED, -1);
//            editor.putLong(PRF_CDT_LAST_VALUE, -1);
//        }else{
            if(tiempo > 0){
                editor.putLong(PRF_CDT_LAST_RECORDED, System.currentTimeMillis());
                editor.putLong(PRF_CDT_LAST_VALUE, tiempo);
            }
//        }
        editor.commit();
        super.onPause();
    }

    private void setupCDT(long lastRecorded, long lastValue){
        long countFrom;
        if(lastRecorded == -1){
            countFrom = 86400000;
        }else{
            long now = System.currentTimeMillis();
            long diff = now - lastRecorded;
            countFrom = lastValue - diff;
        }

        if(countFrom > 0 ) {  // Si es menor a cero es que ya pasó un día.
            cdt = new CountDownTimer(countFrom, 1000) {
                @Override
                public void onTick(long l) {
                   onCount1Sec(l);
                }

                @Override
                public void onFinish() {
                    timeUp();
                }
            };
        }else{
            timeUp();
        }
    }

    private void onCount1Sec(long l){
        tiempo = l;
        updateUi();
    }

    @SuppressLint("ApplySharedPref")
    private void timeUp(){
        cdt = null;
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
        editor.putLong(PRF_CDT_LAST_RECORDED, -1);
        editor.putLong(PRF_CDT_LAST_VALUE, -1);
        editor.commit();
        tiempo = 0;
        updateUi();  
    }

    private void updateUi(){
        if(tiempo > 0) {
            String strTiempo = String.format(new Locale("es"), FORMAT,
                    TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(tiempo),
                    TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(tiempo) - TimeUnit.HOURS.toMinutes(
                            TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(tiempo)),
                    TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(tiempo) - TimeUnit.MINUTES.toSeconds(
                            TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(tiempo)
                    ));
            tvHora.setText(strTiempo);
        }else{
            tvHora.setText("00:00:00");
            tvMsg.setText("Finalizado");
        }
    }

//    private void resetSharedPrefs(){
//       restFlag = true;
//    }
}
```

Comment: Y si pasa mas de un día? la estructura que tienes puede funcionar pero me parece que solo si no logea por un día, pero por ahí puede ir la respuesta.

Comment: Agregué algunas aclaraciones en la parte Edición I

Comment: Me a funcionado, va de perlas.

Answer (score 1):

En mi aplicación también lo que necesitaba era hacer un contador, y como Juan te ha explicado, se puede hacer mediante el uso de services, pero no encontré una buena solución, por lo que se me ocurrió justo lo siguiente que expone Juan: **Hacer uso de *System.currentTimeMillis()***.

Para ello utilicé la fórmula y calculé cuando es 1 día en milisegundos (86.400.000) y se la sumé a los milisegundos actuales para almacenarlo en base de datos (Cloud Firestore):

```
db.collection("nombre_collection_usuarios")
    .document("userID")
    .update("tiempo_recarga", System.currentTimeMillis()+86400000); //Actualizo el campo 'tiempo_recarga' con los (millisegundos_actuales+un_dia_en_milisegundos).
```

Ahora lo que debes hacer es que cada vez que el usuario inicie la app, ésta debe comparar el valor escrito en la base de datos con la fecha actual (usando *System.currentTimeMillis()*). Si la fecha actual es mayor, entonces le muestras un Countdown en 0 o algo que creas conveniente (y si quieres actualizas la base de datos aunque debes tener en cuenta que si el usuario cambia la hora de su dispositivo podrá reiniciar el contador, por lo que debes ingeniarte una forma de evitar esto), de lo contrario, le muestras lo que queda restando ambos valores y listo.

Si no quieres hacer uso de una base de datos online puedes hacerlo de manera local (con SharedPreferences o en un archivo aparte, por ejemplo).

Espero haberte ayudado :)